# VSCode : --jsx flag interferes with auto import suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, tsconfig, typescript3.0

I have a typescript-react project.

When I include the jsx flag in the tsconfig.json file, it messes up the auto import suggestions.

[image: With jsx flag]

If I don't include the jsx flag, auto import suggestions work, but I see errors that I can't use JSX without the --jsx flag as expected.

[image: Without jsx flag]

I have tried playing around with the tsconfig options, but sadly have had no luck.
Have I stumbled upon a VS Code bug or am I missing something very basic?

The relevant tsserver.log entry:

```
Debug Failure.

    Error: Debug Failure.
        at Object.assertDefined (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:2101:24)
        at getDefaultExportInfoWorker (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:118907:80)
        at getDefaultLikeExportInfo (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:118867:24)
        at c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:118850:35
        at c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:119023:21
        at forEachExternalModule (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:119036:21)
        at forEachExternalModuleToImportFrom (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:119021:13)
        at getExportInfos (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:118848:13)
        at getFixesInfoForNonUMDImport (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:118834:57)
        at getFixesInfo (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:118772:50)
        at Object.getCodeActions (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:118533:28)
        at c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:115852:121
        at Object.flatMap (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:583:25)
        at Object.getFixes (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:115852:23)
        at c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:125866:35
        at Object.flatMap (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:583:25)
        at Object.getCodeFixesAtPosition (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:125864:23)
        at IOSession.Session.getCodeFixes (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:135063:64)
        at Session.handlers.ts.createMapFromTemplate._a.(anonymous function) (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:133850:61)
        at c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:135256:88
        at IOSession.Session.executeWithRequestId (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:135247:28)
        at IOSession.Session.executeCommand (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:135256:33)
        at IOSession.Session.onMessage (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:135279:35)
        at Interface.<anonymous> (c:\Codebase\webui\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserver.js:136594:27)
        at Interface.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at Interface._onLine (readline.js:290:10)
        at Interface._normalWrite (readline.js:433:12)
        at Socket.ondata (readline.js:149:10)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
        at Pipe.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

VS Code version: 1.38.1
Typescript version: 3.6.3

**P.S.** Copy-pasting or manually writing imports works, but I believe the IDEs have made us lazy on that front. :)